# how to take user input while in a in loop android?

Tags: android

is it possible to wait for user input before going to next iteration of for loop in android. ?
I generate a textview programmatically according to the String array given.When the loops runs a textview is created and its visibility is set to invisible .Now, what I want to do is when the first iteration of the loop runs i.e when i=0 the textviews options1 options2 options3
are assigned random values with one being equal to arr[i](the correct one).after the options are created the user will input his/her guess  if it is the correct one the dynamic textviews visibility is set to VISIBLE and after that the next next iteration of the loop should run i.e i=1 with new options and so on.. It is possible to do this?

so far my code is like this:

```
    String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c"};
    TextView option_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv1);
    TextView option_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv2);
    TextView option_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv3);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 48));
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textView.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setText(arr[i]);
        textView.setId(i + 1);
        textViewIds[i] = textView.getId();
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final int[] textViewIds = new int[]{R.id.txtv1, R.id.txtv1, R.id.txtv1};
        Random r = new Random();
        int Rand_Tv_no = r.nextInt(textViewIds.length);
        ((TextView) findViewById(textViewIds[Rand_Tv_no])).setText(code[i]);

    }
```

Comment: `is it possible to wait for user input before going to next iteration of for loop in android` no because you freeze the event loop, and your app crashes with ANR (application not responding)

Comment: so it's not possible to do what I asked in the question or is there another way?

Comment: it is possible, but it helps if your code does something reasonable and relevant, and also does not freeze the UI

Comment: Listeners is the way to take input, your code seems it will take high CPU usage.

Comment: I used OnClickListener but  it executed at the last index and did not start from the first one. Like it would only set visible the textview with text 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible by using `AlertDialog` boxes. Create `AlertDialog` in loop, it will generate according by to your loop and create `EditText` box in your alert dialogue.
This is sample code for creating `AlertDialog`

```
   AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AnalogyActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Are You Sure?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               Log.e(TAG, "click: No");

                            }
                        })
                        .create();
                alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                alert.show();
```

Comment: feel free to ask if you've an doubt

Comment: If I use Alert Dialog it also Pops up at the last index and only changes the visibility of textbox  with value " c" like before.Altough it appears 3 times but it only changes the visibility of textbox with value of "c ".

Comment: So, did you try to check? :)